# Add hierarchy of nodes with Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a json in string format, for example

```
{"hello":"Sam"}
```

I want to add a simple nested object at the root level, to get for example

```
{"hello":"Sam", "level1":{"level2":{"level3":"myValue"}}}
```

How do I do this programmatically with Newtonsoft.json, sounds pretty elementary but I am stuck.

I have tried this, but don't know what to write at "level2 node?":

```
var s = @"{""Hello"":""Sam""}";
var jobj = JObject.Parse(s); 
jobj.Add("level1", "level2 node?");
var json2 = jobj.ToString();
```

I probably should use the below Add overload method, which takes a "JToken":
https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Add.htm

But I don't know what this generic JToken is or how to create an instance of it.

And if the hierchical adds should be done "innermost first, or outermost first".

Comment: Please show what you tried.

Comment: If it's already in string format, just stringify the level1 object, and concatenate strings.

Comment: "concatenate strings"? Isn't that what the library helps you with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new `JObject` with the parameterless constructor. You can populate that new child object the same way you're populating the properties of the parent:

```
var json = @"{""hello"":""Sam""}";
var jobj = JObject.Parse(json);

var level2 = new JObject();
level2["level3"] = "myValue";

var level1 = new JObject();
level1["level2"] = level2;

jobj["level1"] = level1;
```

Or you can use [collection initializer syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-initialize-a-dictionary-with-a-collection-initializer), which is possible because `JObject` implements `System.IEnumerable` and has a method `Add(String, JToken)`:

```
var json = @"{""hello"":""Sam""}";
var jobj = JObject.Parse(json);

jobj["level1"] = new JObject
    {
        { "level2", new JObject
            {
                { "level3", "myValue" }
            }
        }
    };
```

You don't have to create a `JToken` explicitly. It has `public static implicit` cast operators for a long list of value types. These classes are well written; they tend to "do what you mean". However, you can call the static method `JToken.FromObject(object o)` if you really want to. You can learn a lot by right-clicking on the JSON.NET classes in Visual Studio and selecting "Go To Definition" from the context menu. Literally everything I learned about this area of JSON.NET, I learned in the last ten minutes by "Go To Definition", and trial and error.